# Finding the integral of rational function of sines

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$ \int \frac{\sin x}{1+\sin x} \, \mathrm{d}x$$ How do I integrate this? I tried multiplying and dividing by $ (1- \sin x) $.

Comment: @Nitin Thanks Nitin, It was of Great Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your idea, $\displaystyle\int\frac{\sin x}{1+\sin x}dx=\int\frac{\sin x}{1+\sin x}\cdot\frac{1-\sin x}{1-\sin x}dx=\int\frac{\sin x-\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x}dx$

$\displaystyle=\int\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2x}dx-\int\tan^2x \;dx=\int\sec x\tan xdx-\int(\sec^2x-1)dx=\sec x-\tan x+x+C$

Answer (score 1):

First, let's simplify things just a bit and write

$$\frac{\sin x}{1+\sin x}=1-\frac{1}{1+\sin x}$$

Then, applying the [Wierstrauss substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution) $u=\tan(x/2)$ with $\sin x=\frac{2u}{1+u^2}$ and $dx=\frac{2du}{1+u^2}$ reveals that

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{\sin x}{1+\sin x}dx&=\int \left(1-\frac{1}{1+\sin x}\right)dx\\\\
&=x-\int\frac{2}{1+u^2+2u}du\\\\
&=x-2\int\frac{1}{(u+1)^2}\\\\
&=x+\frac{2}{1+\tan(x/2)}+C
\end{align}$$

Thus, we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int \frac{\sin x}{1+\sin x}dx=x+\frac{2}{1+\tan(x/2)}+C}$$